# Haskell function with different number of argument

Tags: haskell, typeclass, polyvariadic

I'm trying to create a Haskell function with a class to get this function to work with different numbers of arguments.

```
{-# Language FlexibleInstances #-}

class Titles a where
  titleTeX ::  String -> a

instance Titles String where
  titleTeX str = titleWithFrame 1 "%" "%" "%" [str]

instance  Titles (String -> String) where
  titleTeX str = (\s -> titleWithFrame 1 "%" "%" "%" (s:[str]))

titleWithFrame::Int -> String -> String -> String -> [String] -> String
titleWithFrame nb beg end com lstr =
  cadr++cont++cadr
    where
          cadr = concat $ replicate nb (beg++rempl++end++"\n")
          cont = concatMap (\s -> beg++" "++s++" "++end++"\n") lstr
          rempl = take long $ concat $ replicate long com
          long = (maximum $ map length lstr) + 2
```

When I try this function with ghci, I have the following results:

```
ghci> putStr $ titleTeX "Line 1"
%%%%%%%%%%
% Line 1 %
%%%%%%%%%%
ghci> putStr $ titleTeX "Line 1" "Line 2"
%%%%%%%%%%
% Line 1 %
% Line 2 %
%%%%%%%%%%
ghci> putStr $ titleTeX "Line 1" "Line 2" "Line 3"

<interactive>:4:10: error:
    • No instance for (Main.Titles ([Char] -> [Char] -> String))
        arising from a use of ‘titleTeX’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘titleTeX "Line 1" "Line 2" "Line 3"’
      In the expression: putStr $ titleTeX "Line 1" "Line 2" "Line 3"
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = putStr $ titleTeX "Line 1" "Line 2" "Line 3"
```

I don't understand where my error is and why my polyvariadic function doesn't work with more than 2 arguments.

**Do you know where my error comes from? and How to make my function work with an arbitrary number of arguments?**

Comment: My question was not correctly described. I have modified my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you have exactly two instances of `Titles` in your program:

```
instance Titles String
instance Titles (String -> String)
```

These let you call `titleTeX` with one and two arguments respectively, but three arguments would require

```
instance Titles (String -> String -> String)
```

which doesn't exist. Or as ghc puts it:

```
• No instance for (Main.Titles ([Char] -> [Char] -> String))
    arising from a use of ‘titleTeX’
```

(`[Char]` is the same as `String`.)

It's as if you'd defined a function

```
foo :: [Int] -> Int
foo [x] = ...
foo [x, y] = ...
```

but `foo [x, y, z]` is an error.

To make this work for any number of arguments, we need to use recursion. As with list functions (where you'd typically have a base case `foo [] = ...` and a recursive case `foo (x : xs) = ...` that calls `foo xs` somewhere), we need to define a `Titles` instance in terms of other instances:

```
instance Titles String
instance (Titles a) => Titles (String -> a)
```

The tricky bit is that I don't see a way to implement a `titleTeX` that fits the above declarations.

I had to make other changes to your code to make it work:

```
{-# Language FlexibleInstances #-}

titleTeX :: (Titles a) => String -> a
titleTeX str = titleTeXAccum [str]
```

`titleTeX` isn't a method anymore. It's just a convenience front-end for the actual `titleTeXAccum` method.

In principle we could have omitted the `String` parameter and defined `titleTeX :: (Titles a) => a` as `titleTeX = titleTexAccum []`, but then `titleTex :: String` would crash at runtime (because we end up calling `maximum` on an empty list).

```
class Titles a where
  titleTeXAccum :: [String] -> a
```

Our method now takes a list of strings that it (somehow) turns into a value of type `a`.

```
instance Titles String where
  titleTeXAccum acc = titleWithFrame 1 "%" "%" "%" (reverse acc)
```

The implementation for `String` is easy: We just call `titleWithFrame`. We also pass `reverse acc` because the order of elements in the accumulator is backwards (see below).

```
instance (Titles a) => Titles (String -> a) where
  titleTeXAccum acc str = titleTeXAccum (str : acc)
```

This is the crucial part: The general `titleTeXAccum` method forwards to another `titleTeXAccum` method (of a different type / different `Titles` instance). It adds `str` to the accumulator. We could have written `acc ++ [str]` to add the new element at the end, but that's inefficient: Calling `titleTeXAccum` with N elements would take O(N^2) time (due to repeated list traversals in `++`). Using `:` and only calling `reverse` once at the end reduces this to O(N).

Comment: Perfect and well detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

It works if you use the function you presented, `titleTeX`, and not some other function you have yet to show, `titleLaTeX`.